# Matrix param not working in jax-rs web services using jersey

Tags: web-services, rest, matrix, parameters, jax-rs

I am using following code for matrix param in web services using jersey.
All variables in the method getFromMatrixParam() are getting value from the uri except color variable which is supposed to get value from matrix param in uri.

Can some one explain me why it is not working

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.MatrixParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/cars")
public class CarResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/matrix/{car}/{model}/{year}")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getFromMatrixParam(@PathParam("car") String car, @PathParam("model") String model, @MatrixParam("color") String color, @PathParam("year") String year) {
        return "A " +  color + " " + car + " " + model + " of " + year +  " made";
    }
}
```

URI used to invoke the above method is as below :

http://localhost:8080/Webservice_Restful_BBCH05d_Matrix_Parameter/webapi/cars/matrix/honda/city;color=black/2015

The value of color is coming as null.
The output of the above uri is :

"A null honda city of 2015 made"

Can some explain me why matrix param is not getting populated with proper value from uri ?

Answer (score 0):

`@Matrix Param` is, currently, not work except in last path.

You can get with like this

```
public String getFromMatrixParam(
     ...,
     @PathSegment("city") cityPath,
     ...) {
    String color = cityPath.getMatrixParameters().get("color");
}
```